# Get product categories for specific store in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, stores

I want to get category names assigned to particular product for current store.
I have 2 store wholesale ans retail.
I want to get the category name assigned to a product for retail store only. how can i do that?
I tried using object manager, below is my code. it fetches the category from both the store for now. but i want only for current store.

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')- 
>registry('current_product');//get current product
$categoryCollection = $objectManager- 
>get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
  $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();

$productId =  $product->getId();
$product = $productRepository->getById($productId);

 $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

$categories = $categoryCollection->create()
                             ->setStoreId($storeId)
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds); 
        ?>
```